# Access $HOME variable from node js child_process?

Tags: node.js, linux

It seems like I can't access the `$HOME` property within my nodeJS app when running a `child_process` on my Linux machine:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

var testHome = `echo $HOME`

testHomeCmd = exec(testHome)
testHomeCmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Where the output I receive is: `[17597]: /`

If I run `echo $HOME` in terminal I receive:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/cs4
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you run `node yourfile.js` on that same terminal, do you get the same result? Different accounts have different home directories, so if you run your server as a different user then the data won't correspond to your login user.

Comment: I've actually packaged the node app into `RPM` and I run it with `systemctl start`. If I run a simple `node testfile.js` with the above, it spits out the home directory properly.

Comment: Sounds like it's working as intended then. Are you instead trying to find the home directory of a given user on the system? Or are you trying to have `systemctl` run this process as your user?

Comment: I think what may make sense is have `systemctl` run the process as my user. (I'm assuming it runs as `root` by default?)

Comment: Did you try accessing the variable like this: `var testHome=process.env.HOME` ?